# Matlab image filtering without using conv2

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, filtering, convolution

I've been given a task to create image filtering function for 3x3 matrices, and its outcome must be equal to conv2's. I have written this function, but it filters image incorrectly:

```
function [ image ] = Func134( img,matrix )
  image=img;
  len=length(img)
  for i=2:1:len-1
    for j=2:1:len-1
      value=0;
      for g=-1:1:1
        for l=-1:1:1
          value=value+img(i+g,j+l)*matrix(g+2,l+2);
        end
      end
     image(i,j)=value;
    end
  end
i=1:1:length
image(i,1)=image(i,2)
image(i,len)=image(i,len-1)
image(1,i)=image(2,i)
image(len,i)=image(len-1,i)
end
```

Filtration matrix is [3,10,3;0,0,0;-3,-10,-3]

Please help to figure out what is wrong with my code.

Some sample results I get between `conv2` and my code are seen below.

[image: Image processing results]

Comment: Define "incorrectly". Have you used the debugger to help isolate your problem? What were the results? What does `i=1:1:length` mean?

Comment: The code below i=1:1:length fills unfiltered border pixels with their filtered neighbours

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're getting and what you expect. Did you remember to cast your img as `double` or `single`?

Comment: I didn't ask about the code below that line, I asked about what that line is supposed to mean because it isn't valid MATLAB.

Comment: Iength should be len

Comment: No, i didn't cast anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, this line doesn't make sense:

```
i=1:1:length;
```

I think you meant to use `len` instead of `length` as the ending index:

```
i=1:1:len;
```

Now referring to your code, it is correct, but what you are doing is **correlation** not convolution.  In 2D convolution, you have to perform a 180 degree rotation of the kernel / mask and then do the weighted sum.  As such, if you want to achieve the same results using `conv2`, you **must** pre-rotate the mask before calling it.

```
mask = [3,10,3;0,0,0;-3,-10,-3]
mask_flip = mask(end:-1:1,end:-1:1);
out = conv2(img, mask, 'same');
```

`mask_flip` contains the 180 degree rotated kernel.  We use the `'same'` flag to ensure that the output size of the result is the same size as the input.  However, when using `conv2`, we are assuming that the borders of the image are zero-padded.  Your code simply copies the border pixels of the original image into the resulting image.  This is known as replicating behaviour but that is not what `conv2` does natively.  `conv2` assumes that the border pixels are zero-padded as I mentioned before, so what I would suggest you do is create two additional images, one being the output image that has 2 more rows and 2 more columns and another being the input image that is the same size as the output image but you place the input image inside this matrix. Next, perform the filtering on this new image, place the resulting filtered pixels in the output image then crop this result.  I've decided to create a new padded input image in order to keep most of your code intact.

I would also recommend that you abolish the use of `length` here.  Use [`size`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) instead to determine the image dimensions.  Something like this will work:

```
function [ image ] = Func134( img,matrix )
  [rows,cols] = size(img); %// Change

  %// New - Create a padded matrix that is the same class as the input
  new_img = zeros(rows+2,cols+2);
  new_img = cast(new_img, class(img));

  %// New -  Place original image in padded result
  new_img(2:end-1,2:end-1) = img;

  %// Also create new output image the same size as the padded result
  image = zeros(size(new_img));
  image = cast(image, class(img));

  for i=2:1:rows+1 %// Change
    for j=2:1:cols+1 %// Change
      value=0;
      for g=-1:1:1
        for l=-1:1:1
          value=value+new_img(i+g,j+l)*matrix(g+2,l+2); %// Change
        end
      end
     image(i,j)=value;
    end
  end

%// Change
%// Crop the image and remove the extra border pixels
image = image(2:end-1,2:end-1);
end
```

---

To compare, I've generated this random matrix:

```
>> rng(123);
>> A = rand(10,10)

A =

    0.6965    0.3432    0.6344    0.0921    0.6240    0.1206    0.6693    0.0957    0.3188    0.7050
    0.2861    0.7290    0.8494    0.4337    0.1156    0.8263    0.5859    0.8853    0.6920    0.9954
    0.2269    0.4386    0.7245    0.4309    0.3173    0.6031    0.6249    0.6272    0.5544    0.3559
    0.5513    0.0597    0.6110    0.4937    0.4148    0.5451    0.6747    0.7234    0.3890    0.7625
    0.7195    0.3980    0.7224    0.4258    0.8663    0.3428    0.8423    0.0161    0.9251    0.5932
    0.4231    0.7380    0.3230    0.3123    0.2505    0.3041    0.0832    0.5944    0.8417    0.6917
    0.9808    0.1825    0.3618    0.4264    0.4830    0.4170    0.7637    0.5568    0.3574    0.1511
    0.6848    0.1755    0.2283    0.8934    0.9856    0.6813    0.2437    0.1590    0.0436    0.3989
    0.4809    0.5316    0.2937    0.9442    0.5195    0.8755    0.1942    0.1531    0.3048    0.2409
    0.3921    0.5318    0.6310    0.5018    0.6129    0.5104    0.5725    0.6955    0.3982    0.3435
```

Now running with what we talked about above:

```
mask = [3,10,3;0,0,0;-3,-10,-3];
mask_flip = mask(end:-1:1,end:-1:1);
B = Func134(A,mask);
C = conv2(A, mask_flip,'same');
```

We get the following for your function and the output of `conv2`:

```
>> B

B =

   -5.0485  -10.6972  -11.9826   -7.2322   -4.9363  -10.3681  -10.9944  -12.6870  -12.5618  -12.0295
    4.4100    0.1847   -2.2030   -2.7377    0.6031   -3.7711   -2.5978   -5.8890   -2.9036    2.7836
   -0.6436    6.6134    4.2122   -0.7822   -2.3282    1.6488    0.4420    2.2619    4.2144    3.2372
   -4.8046   -1.0665    0.1568   -1.5907   -4.6943    0.3036    0.4399    4.3466   -2.5859   -3.4849
   -0.7529   -5.5344    1.3900    3.1715    2.9108    4.6771    7.0247    1.7062   -3.9277   -0.6497
   -1.9663    2.4536    4.2516    2.2266    3.6084    0.6432   -1.0581   -3.4674    5.3815    6.1237
   -0.9296    5.1244    0.8912   -7.7325  -10.2260   -6.4585   -1.4298    6.2675   10.1657    5.3225
    3.9511   -1.7869   -1.9199   -5.0832   -3.2932   -2.9853    5.5304    5.9034    1.4683   -0.7394
    1.8580   -3.8938   -3.9216    3.8254    5.4139    1.8404   -4.3850   -7.4159   -4.9894   -0.5096
    6.4040    7.6395    7.3643   11.8812   10.6537   10.8957    5.0278    3.0277    4.2295    3.3229

>> C

C =

   -5.0485  -10.6972  -11.9826   -7.2322   -4.9363  -10.3681  -10.9944  -12.6870  -12.5618  -12.0295
    4.4100    0.1847   -2.2030   -2.7377    0.6031   -3.7711   -2.5978   -5.8890   -2.9036    2.7836
   -0.6436    6.6134    4.2122   -0.7822   -2.3282    1.6488    0.4420    2.2619    4.2144    3.2372
   -4.8046   -1.0665    0.1568   -1.5907   -4.6943    0.3036    0.4399    4.3466   -2.5859   -3.4849
   -0.7529   -5.5344    1.3900    3.1715    2.9108    4.6771    7.0247    1.7062   -3.9277   -0.6497
   -1.9663    2.4536    4.2516    2.2266    3.6084    0.6432   -1.0581   -3.4674    5.3815    6.1237
   -0.9296    5.1244    0.8912   -7.7325  -10.2260   -6.4585   -1.4298    6.2675   10.1657    5.3225
    3.9511   -1.7869   -1.9199   -5.0832   -3.2932   -2.9853    5.5304    5.9034    1.4683   -0.7394
    1.8580   -3.8938   -3.9216    3.8254    5.4139    1.8404   -4.3850   -7.4159   -4.9894   -0.5096
    6.4040    7.6395    7.3643   11.8812   10.6537   10.8957    5.0278    3.0277    4.2295    3.3229
```