# Octave Arguments Error in Image Convolution 2d

Tags: image, matlab, 2d, octave, convolution

I need to write a 2d convolution function that will return the same result with conv2.

I found an alternative to conv2 but returns 2 more than the conv2's result and it causes an error.

Here is the convolution function I found [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439489/matlab-image-filtering-without-using-conv2/35439993#35439993):

```
function [ conv_res ] = convolve_im( im,filter )

[rows,cols] = size(im);
new_img = zeros(rows+2,cols+2);
new_img = cast(new_img, class(im));
new_img(2:end-1,2:end-1) = im;

conv_res = zeros(size(new_img));
conv_res = cast(conv_res, class(im));

for i=2:1:rows+1
    for j=2:1:cols+1
        value=0;
        for g=-1:1:1
            for l=-1:1:1
                value=value+new_img(i+g,j+l) * filter(g+2,l+2);
            end
        end
        conv_res(i,j)=value;
    end
end
conv_res = conv_res(2:end-1,2:end-1);
end
```

And this is how i compare the result with conv2:

```
img = imread('puppy.jpeg');
conv_ok =1;
test_filter=[0 -1 0; -1 4 -1; 0 -1 0];

conv_res = convolve_im(img, test_filter);
ground_res = conv2(img,test_filter, 'valid');

check = abs(ground_res) - abs(conv_res);  % Line 24
if sum(abs(check(:,:))) ==0

    disp('Convolution for 3x3 works fine.');
else
    conv_ok = 0;
    disp('Convolution part is wrong for 3x3!!!');
end
```

And this is the runtime error  i am getting:

**nonconformant arguments (op1 is 211x234, op2 is 213x236) at line 24**

How can i fix this error? Thanks.

Edit: After changing 'valid' with 'same', it no longer gives an error but it displays 'Convolution part is wrong for 3x3!!!'

Here is the test function after editing:

```
img = imread('puppy.jpeg');
conv_ok =1;
test_filter=[0 -1 0; -1 4 -1; 0 -1 0]; %laplace filter 3x3

conv_res = convolve_im(img, test_filter);

ground_res = conv2(img,test_filter, 'same');

check = abs(ground_res) - abs(conv_res);


if sum(abs(check(:,:))) ==0

disp('Convolution for 3x3 works fine.');
else

conv_ok = 0;
disp('Convolution part is wrong for 3x3!!!');

end
```

Comment: In the future you should reference where you got the code from. I have added a link to your question to where you actually found it - fortunately I found the link as it was code that I used in a previous answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the flag of your `conv2` operation from `'valid'` to `'same'`.  When you are subtracting the ground truth and convolved images together, the convolution result from `valid` is smaller because you want to output an image where the filtering results come from the kernel being fully encased in the image.  Using `'same'` will certainly zero-pad the borders like what is done in the custom code you provided ([looks familiar btw...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439489/matlab-image-filtering-without-using-conv2/35439993#35439993)) and ensures that the output size is the same as the input.  In fact, the custom code specifically does `'same'` padding.

Further, you are convolving with a 3 x 3 kernel, so the final output will remove 2 rows and 2 columns to ensure that you are returning results that are valid or where the kernel is fully inside the image.

In addition, you must **change** the data type of your image.  Currently your image is unsigned 8-bit integer.  Because you are using an edge detection, any output values that are negative will be truncated to 0 so you will definitely not get the right results.  Therefore, convert your image to `double` first prior to filtering your image.  You can do that by just casting to `double`.  I'm opting to use this instead of `im2double` because you want to check for equality of images and doing this is better when your image pixels are not fractional.

You thus need to make the following changes:

```
img = imread('puppy.jpeg');
img = double(img); % Change
conv_ok = 1;
test_filter=[0 -1 0; -1 4 -1; 0 -1 0]; %laplace filter 3x3

conv_res = convolve_im(img, test_filter);
ground_res = conv2(img,test_filter, 'same'); % Change

check = abs(ground_res) - abs(conv_res);

if sum(abs(check(:,:))) ==0
    disp('Convolution for 3x3 works fine.');
else
    conv_ok = 0;
    disp('Convolution part is wrong for 3x3!!!');
end
```

Comment: Hello, firstly thanks for your answer and sorry for not referencing your post.

Comment: But unfortunately it didn't fix the problem, when i changed it to 'same' the numbers in the error message has changed. It is now : 'nonconformant arguments (op1 is 209x232, op2 is 213x236)'

Comment: You're definitely not using it correctly. It looks like you're using `conv2` twice on the same input.  Please clear all of your variables and try again.  Also please update your question to show your changes.  I can't tell if you're using the changes correctly.

Comment: Edited, it doesnt give an error but it says 'Convolution part is wrong'.

Comment: Please provide the actual image you're using. I suspect it is due to conflicting variable types.

Comment: @MuhammedGül Figured it out.  It's because of the types of your image.  I'll update my post.

Comment: Thank you so much, i am looking forward.

Comment: @MuhammedGül I've finished. Have a look.

Comment: @MuhammedGül lol you're very welcome.  I will admit that a lot of problems in image processing deal with not being aware of the input data type into algorithms.  Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again but how can i make this function also work with 5x5 filter (second part of my homework)? I tried it with the following filter and it gives output 'wrong for 5x5 convolution'. Filter: test_filter=[0 0 -1 0 0; 0 -1 -1 -1 0; -1 -1 12 -1 -1; 0 -1 -1 -1 0; 0 0 -1 0 0];

Comment: The custom convolution code is only meant for a 3 x 3 filter.  To go to 5 x 5, you must modify some of the constants.

Comment: When I get the chance I'll modify

Comment: That would be so great sir, looking forward for it.